# C and GTK3 - Application menu not showing when using Glade

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

I am having trouble getting the correct application menu showing when using Glade (GtkBuilder). This is the code I am currently using:

### main.c:

```
void app_init(GtkApplication* app, void* userdata)
{
    (void)userdata;
    GActionEntry appactions[] = {
        {"about", app_aboutaction, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0}},
        {"quit", app_quitaction, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0}},
    };

    g_action_map_add_action_entries(
        G_ACTION_MAP(app),
        appactions,
        sizeof appactions / sizeof *appactions,
        app
    );

    GMenu* menu = g_menu_new();
    g_menu_append(menu, "About", "app.about");
    g_menu_append(menu, "Quit", "app.quit");

    gtk_application_set_app_menu(app, G_MENU_MODEL(menu));
}

void app_ctor(GtkApplication* app, void* userdata)
{
    (void)userdata;

    GtkBuilder* builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("./builder.ui");
    GtkWindow* appwin = GTK_WINDOW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window"));
    gtk_window_set_application(appwin, app);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GtkApplication* app = gtk_application_new(NULL, G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "startup", G_CALLBACK(app_init), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(app_ctor), NULL);

    return g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
}
```

## builder.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

### Resulting application menu:

[image: result]

### Expected application menu:

[image: expected result]

I believe that it has something to do with me not calling the application window constructor, since it is created with GtkBuilder or something like that.

Any ideas to what I can do?

Comment: Check this [example](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/examples/application4). It seems you have to subclass GtkApplicationWindow and GtkApplication.

Comment: @JoséFonte The thing is that it will work as expected if I use `gtk_application_window_new(app)` instead of `GtkBuilder`

Comment: @libforce for coherency i suggest editing the same code on the question. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem resides on the ui builder file with the visible flag set as true:

> a (application) window has to have a GtkApplication instance assigned
>   *before* it's shown

So, set the builder.ui Visible property to False:

```
<property name="visible">False</property>
```

As the window is not being shown, you must do it manually after setting the application, e.g. gtk_window_present:

```
void app_ctor(GtkApplication* app, G_GNUC_UNUSED gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkBuilder* builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("./builder.ui");
    GtkWindow* appwin = GTK_WINDOW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window"));
    gtk_window_set_application(appwin, app);
    gtk_window_present(appwin);
}
```

Comment: @libforce thanks for edit, i kept the same code as the original. The intent was solving the problem not correcting the code. Thanks, all the best.

Comment: In fact I saw that was in the original code *after* my edit ;), but it's nonetheless a useful feature to learn. Cheers :)

Comment: @liberforce Isn't `(void)userdata` more standard? As in not depending on gcc extensions?

Comment: @ErikW gpointer is similar to void *, it's just a typedef: `typedef void* gpointer;` check [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Basic-Types.html#gpointer).

Comment: @JoséFonte: he's talking about the G_GNU_UNUSED bit.

Comment: @ErikW: Well, of course, it won't work if the compiler is not gcc. But I like the clarity and semantics. Casting an unused variable doesn't say why this is done. Using something that says it's because it's unused gives a better code. If you're not using gcc, you may still redefine the macro or search and replace for it, which you wouldn't be able to do with a simple cast.

Comment: @liberforce Oh sry, didn't get that. In fact, it's not usual to prefix it that way but it doesn't hurt too unless you use it to pass data afterwards.

Comment: Thanks: this fixed the same problem for me. However: Where is the quote from? i.e. where does GTK+ document this?

Comment: @underscore_d it's a quote from the developers of Gtk, not sure if it's documented but i'm almost sure i've read that somewhere. Good Luck

Comment: @JoséFonte OK, thanks. This goes in my list of 'weird things you just have to do in GTK+, for some reason'. I'm currently dealing with `GtkShortcutsShortcut` and friends again, and remembering how this group of widgets has almost no real API, almost no real documentation, and a lot of odd quirks for which I have to write explanatory comments in my source. The `Shortcuts` widgets were clearly not aimed at anyone writing code, only .ui files. :S

Comment: @underscore_d Indeed, Gtk tips and hints are scattered all around on the internet. There's a lot of information on GNOME reference API but many are not fully documented. Unfortunately the community is not so big and the effort is huge. [Check this](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/ApplicationMenu). As last resort, you can go to irc and talk with the devs.

Comment: @JoséFonte Yup! I have seen a few of the "HowDoI" articles, and they have been very good. Maybe sometime I'll get some of these details added to them. I do go on IRC and have had some great help there, but it's hit or miss whether anyone who knows the answer is there, and sometimes instead of help it's just 'but why do you want to do that?'... which is often a fair question, but sometimes it just gets in the way. :P